# Save SQL Query for later, or upload this data as a column on my database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to save the following query to calculate the average of the numbers in my database. These are student grades and I want to calculate an average to trace their progress.

Alternatively I just want to be able to create an average of three columns worth of data and create an average for each student.

This is my query:

```
SELECT AVG (grade + grade2 +grade3) /3 FROM studentresults
```

Comment: You mean that you want save the result of the query (related  to a date )?

Comment: do you mean calculated column?? do you wish to add this as a column for your table?

Comment: I want to save the result, data has been submitted using a simple php form. This data exists in my database.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I guess so, can this be done.

Comment: We cant answer this if you dont show your table structure and some example data

Comment: I suggest that you simply run your select query whenever you need to see an average and display the results wherever.  Don't worry about storing them.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4UDAgyIfxjHaDQzbkt3S2lMZGM/view?usp=sharing @RaymondNijland

Comment: @c9mber dont screen shot the data make an export from the table.

Comment: @c9mber check this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want average of three columns for each student/row, you can use

```
SELECT (grade + grade2 +grade3)/3 as avg_score,student_id FROM studentresults
```